# I am getting syntax error in jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
/data/jenkins/workspace/Clean Up SonarQube/clean-up-sonarqube@tmp/durable-a32f78e4/script.sh: 16: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 2
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 2s
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have a Jenkins job to clean up sonarqube projects depend on gitlab projects .
The api in the script is not listing all branches from GITLAB. But if we run the api separately we get all the branches , the api is not working in the script . This issue result into a major issue of deleting the sonarqube projects.
I have checked the GitLab, Jenkinsfile but I did not get any issue. So, what exactly is the issue here I am not able to figure out.

Comment: Git does not have "API calls" in this manner. GitLab *does* have REST APIs, but that's not what you're hitting. Your problem has nothing to do with Git or GitLab or sonarqube, it's just a coding error in some script you're running with Jenkins.

Comment: Please share your Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: I have added the jenkinsfile. @ycr

Comment: Obviously, the error is thrown from one of your `shell` scripts. SO without looking at them we really can't answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
script.sh: 16: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I would first copy the content of that script to [`shellcheck.net`](https://www.shellcheck.net/), in order to detect any obvious error.

I would then try and execute it locally, to see if and how it behaves.

Then and only then I would try it again in the GitLab runner.